# POSTGRESQL Trigger that updates a column after having altered the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, alter-table

I have a populated table that already has some specific columns. I'd like to alter the table structure by adding a new column which will represent a field that is the count of the rows of another table.

Is it possible to implement it through a trigger in order to do it automatically after the alter command?
I have come up with something like this but apparently doesn't update the column:

Function for the trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_column() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
num INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num FROM mytable1, mytable2 WHERE mytable1.field = mytable2.field GROUP BY mytable1.field;
    UPDATE mytable1 SET new_column = num;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert
AFTER UPDATE
ON mytable1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_column();
```

And the alter command:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable1 ADD new_column INT;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are running MySQL? This is Postgres syntax.

Comment: @GMB You're right my bad

Comment: This would be very inefficient. `new_column` contains no new information anyway so better create a view with all mytable1 columns plus the `select count` sub-query as an extra column instead of changing the structure of mytable1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement it through a trigger in order to do it automatically after the alter command?

Firstly, your trigger fires after each `update` on the table, not after the `alter table`. Second, there would not be much point for a trigger on such DDL event anyway.

If your table has data already, you might need to initialize the column after its creation, with something like:

```
update mytable1 t1
set new_column = (select count(*) from mytable2 t2 where t2.field = t1.field)
```

As for the logic you wanted in the trigger: you need to use `new` and `old` to refer to the row that was changed in the original table - and, typically, you would expect the update to affect either no rows (if `field` was not changed), or two rows (if it was):

```
update mytable1 t1
set new_column = (select count(*) from mytable2 t2 where t2.field = t1.field)
where t1.field in (new.field, old.field) and new.field <> old.field
```

That said, I would not recommend such set up. Maintaining such derived information is expensive and tedious (you have an `update` trigger, now you need an `insert` and a `delete` trigger too). Instead, you can compute the logic on the fly when needed, or create a view:

```
create view myview as
select t1.*, 
    (select count(*) from mytable2 t2 where t2.field = t1.field) as new_column
from mytable1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not set this value automatically in a trigger based on when the column is *added*.  You would use a trigger to maintain the value when there are changes on the second table.

The process is:

1. Add the column with a default value:

   ```
    alter table mytable1 add new_column int default 0;
   ```
2. Initialize the value of the column to the current values:

   ```
    update mytable1 t1
        set new_column = (select count(*) from mytable2 t2 where t2.field = t1.field);
   ```
3. Add insert/update/delete triggers on `mytable2`.  The key logic is:

   ```
    update mytable1
         set cnt = cnt + 1
         where t1.field = new.field;

    update mytable1
         set cnt = cnt - 1
         where t1.field = old.field;
   ```

If you don't have a foreign key relationship, you may also need to insert a row in `mytable1` if the `field` value is not in the table.  However, I strongly recommend an explicit `foreign key` constraint to prevent this from happening.

This increments/decrements the value when changes are made to the *second* table.